# sets and finding counterexample from empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question
Find a counter-example to the claim that for all sets $A,B,C$ if $A\cap B=B\cap C=A\cap C=\emptyset$ then $A\cap B\cap C\neq\emptyset$.

If i have to find a counter-example then It should be an example or fact that is inconsistent with a hypothesis and may be used in argument against it.

Can i get help here please.